# use of Jacobian with a multiple integral

Tags: calculus

To solve the following integral
  $\int \int_{D} \frac{y-x}{2x+y}\\ \\ \\
y=4+x,y=1+x,y=6-2x,y=8-2x$
I changed the variables to be:
$y-x=4,y-x=1,y+2x=6,y+2x=8$
and then to:
$U=y-x,V=y+2x$
Now U and V are functions of x and y
is it correct to calculate the Jacobian in this way?
$\left |\frac{D(U,V)}{D(x,y)}\right |^{-1}$

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking if, in your example: $\frac{D(U,V)}{D(x,y)}=(\frac{D(x,y)}{D(U,V)})^{-1}$   ?

If that's the case...

First off all, remember that $\frac{D(x,y)}{D(U,V)}$ is a notation to the determinant of the jacobian of $(U^{-1}(x,y), V^{-1}(x,y))$.

Then notice your change of variables is a bijective linear apllication from ${R}^{2}$ to $R^{2}$ (just restricted to $G^{-1}(D)$), therefore its inverse exists and is a linear apllication.
This also means that the jacobian of $(U(x,y), V(x,y))$ is the inverse matrix of the jacobian of $(U^{-1}(x,y), V^{-1}(x,y))$ (since the determinant of the first is non-zero, because it's bijective, and we are dealing with matrices of the type
\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}).

This way, we conclude that $\frac{D(U,V)}{D(x,y)}=(\frac{D(x,y)}{D(U,V)})^{-1}$ for any change of variables U and V that form a bijective linear application (which is almost always the case).